# PIC32 Ethernet kit and UDP

Tags: c, udp, pic

I have a [PIC32 ethernet evaluation board](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/DM320004/DM320004-ND/2184479) and I am trying to get it to send a simple UDP packet.

Here is my code so far:

```
/*
 * This macro uniquely defines this file as the main entry point.
 * There should only be one such definition in the entire project,
 * and this file must define the AppConfig variable as described below.
 */
#define THIS_IS_STACK_APPLICATION

// Include all headers for any enabled TCPIP Stack functions
#include "TCPIP Stack/TCPIP.h" 
#include "TCPIPConfig.h"

#include <plib.h>
#include <p32xxxx.h>

// Declare AppConfig structure and some other supporting stack variables
APP_CONFIG AppConfig;
BYTE AN0String[8];

int main()
{
    static enum
    {
        SM_OPEN,
        SM_BROADCAST,
    } smState = SM_OPEN;
    typedef BYTE UDPSocket;
    UDP_SOCKET s;
    NODE_INFO myRemoteNode;

    myRemoteNode.IPAddr.v[0]=169;
    myRemoteNode.IPAddr.v[1]=254;
    myRemoteNode.IPAddr.v[2]=2;
    myRemoteNode.IPAddr.v[3]=2;
    myRemoteNode.MACAddr.v[0]=0x01;
    myRemoteNode.MACAddr.v[1]=0xA0;
    myRemoteNode.MACAddr.v[2]=0xF0; 
    myRemoteNode.MACAddr.v[3]=0x7B;
    myRemoteNode.MACAddr.v[4]=0xE5;
    myRemoteNode.MACAddr.v[5]=0x45;

    TRISD = 0xff00; // tri-state register for the LED ports

    // Initialize UDP
    UDPInit();

    while(1)
    {
        switch(smState)
        {
            case SM_OPEN:

                // Talk to a remote DHCP server.
                s = UDPOpen(68, &myRemoteNode, 67);

                if ( s == INVALID_UDP_SOCKET )
                {
                    PORTD = 0x01; // Switch on the red LED on PIC32 ethernet starter kit to indicate an error 
                    // Socket is not available
                    // Return error.
                }
                else
                    // Broadcast DHCP Broadcast message.
                    smState = SM_BROADCAST;
                break;

            case SM_BROADCAST:

                PORTD = 0x02; // Switch on the yellow LED to indicate the connection

                if ( UDPIsPutReady(s) )
                {
                    // Turn on yellow and green LED to indicate UDP is put ready
                    PORTD = 0x06;   

                    // Socket is ready to transmit. Transmit the data...
                    // Note that there is DHCPSocket parameter in UDPPut.
                    // This UDPPut call will use active socket
                    // as set by UDPIsPutReady() - that is DHCPSocket.
                    UDPPut(0x55);

                    // Now transmit it.
                    UDPFlush();
                }
                UDPClose(s);                
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile and run the code in MPLAB IDE, it looks like the board sends two packets, then nothing. I hooked up the board directly to a laptop PC running Wireshark, but Wireshark could not detect any received packets.

I was able to successfully get the board to run the http server demo, which uses TCP, so I know it isn't a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

This question really needs to be in electronic stack exchange or mc forums.  I think the problem is that the first 2 seconds or so after initialization that the packets never get to or past the phy.  I don't know why, but I have run across this just recently.  I think your code is fine, although I would use UDPOpenEx, assuming you have fairly late Microchip App libs.  Try waiting a few seconds, or resend.  If you connect as a IP instead of NODE_INFO, it will arp and probably work, because the arp will have to resolve first.